# To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, rfacebook

[image: Facebook app review approval]

As you can see in the screenshot above, I got Facebook app review approval but now I tried to access Facebook public page posts and comments per page. Still, I am getting bellow massage in R Console:

Error in `callAPI(url = url, token = token, api = api)`:

> (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

Comment: When you solve that by recording the webpage with very temporary Page Access Token, you will get the next rejection "We can't find FB login button on your app" (wtf?!)

Comment: how to prepare metadata without getting approval?

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. Did you send the request to get a permission? How many days it took? It really sucks that to get *public* posts you have to get a permission.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I got Facebook app review approval

No, you didn’t ...

[image]

You filled out all the necessary info, so that you now *can* submit your review - that’s what those green check marks mean.

If you actually *had* this reviewed already, then it would show a green circle in front of the permissions, and would not show “Edit Details”.

Comment: I have submitted for review. Don’t know when they will review it?

Comment: can you please tell me, how many days it will take to get approval?

Comment: It used to be “up to 5 business days” under the old system; but I think you can expect much longer times currently, because a lot of people will be submitting their apps right now.

Comment: @CBroe can you guide me to submit the app for approval, because I had submitted the app for review but they rejected the 'Page Public Content Access' permission & provide the feedback as :                            ** Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app. Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually.
All permissions data must be visibly used within your app. We do not accept permission requests for data that you may decide to use later.**

Comment: @KabirB But how are we suppose to make data visible when we dont have permission to do so? :3

Comment: Did you find any solution to be able to show Facebook how we are supposed to use this permission ? We have the exact same problem...

Comment: I am having the exact same problem

Comment: Same issue :((( Any solutions...??

Comment: This is definitely not their killing feature

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck in an infinite loop of app approval (Facebook doesn't want to approve your app because "use case data is not visible") I think that the only solution is to temporary create your own page (or use some of your existing pages) and then crawl that page's content.

Here's what the Facebook say about "Page public content access":

> "While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app. If you want the app to be able to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this feature for review. Once you set your app to live mode, it will not be able to see any Page public content without this feature."

Comment: This is not true, I am the admin of the app and the page, and still getting the same stupid response "Your screencast bla bla" and after 3 more submissions I got "We can't find FB login button on your app". IT'S DAMN WEBSITE! WHY DO I NEED TO HAVE LOGIN BUTTON TO READ PUBLIC POSTS FROM MY FB PAGE?!

Comment: Same problem here!  Any solution yet?

Comment: Does anyone know what constitutes "the person"? My Wordpress user who is the owner of the Page has the same email address as the Facebook account that is the app's administrator. i thought this would be enough, yet I still get the same error message.

Comment: I think they meant "user access token" not "app access token" and yes, it's working with first type of token

Comment: I think the problem is that Facebook has gotten so much bad press in regards to privacy that they are happy to just scuttle their public API for smaller developers. I guarantee you the big names won't be affected but all smaller developers will have huge headaches now :(

Answer (score 0):

If your app need access token for a page that has same admin as the app then you can get it using manage_pages permission, otherwise (for pages has different admins)  you need "Page Public Content Access" permission.